# Does console.log work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Does **console.log** work in Javascript?
I mean for producing output on screen like:

**console.log("Hello World!")**

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce an output on the screen, as I understand you to mean, one would use the `alert()` command to produce a pop-up; the `console.log()` command is used to send data to the console, which is not shown to the viewer by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the console to see the log. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.